# XStream TreeSetConverter

Tags: java, xstream, treeset

I'm having problems while trying to unmarshall XML into ValueObjects, because there are TreeSets along the way.

I've read it is necessary to implement a TreeSetConverter, in order to make it work, but I still don't understand why:

[http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization_implicit_different_type](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Serialization_implicit_different_type)

And I've found this sample of TreeSetConverter:

http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/xstream/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/TreeSetConverter.java.html

I've read on XStream site about implicit collections:

> "that collections with additional information (e.g. a TreeSet with a Comparator) cannot be restored, since the comparator was already
> omitted at serialization time".

Does this mean I can't marshall/unmarshall ValueObjects with TreeSets?

About TreeSetconverter:

> Converts a java.util.TreeSet to XML, and serializes the associated java.util.Comparator.
> The converter assumes that the elements in the XML are already sorted according the comparator.
>
> This is similar to CollectionConverter with an additional field for
> storing the java.util.Comparator associated with the TreeSet.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I've tried to implement and use the converter given, but couldn't register the converter to the XStream instance, once it's constructor asks for a Mapper, and I couldn't instantiate it. It seems is very complicated to work with TreeSets and XStream.

Comment: I've just found a solution for this problem. And it was to generate a XSD schema from my XML file. After this, to generate a new ValueObject from the XSD schema. After this, I've just unmarshalled the XML into the generated ValueObject, using JAXB, and it worked fine. The ValueObject is populated with the data from the XML.